# I'm getting error in this part it will sum the value of array1[0][2] and array1[1][1],and it not adding array1[2][0], .Can some find the error?

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix

I was calculating the absolute difference between the sums of its diagonals of a square matrix.

I got an error while calculating 2nd diagonal sum(sum2)

Can anyone please give where is an error and I'm using c++ 14 version

this was my input:

[image]

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
int n{};
cin >> n;
int array1[n][n]{};


for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            cin>>array1[i][j];
    }
}

int sum1{0};
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            if(i==j){
                sum1+=array1[i][j];
            }
    }
}
cout<<sum1;

/*i'm getting error in this part it will sum the value of  array1[0][2] and array1[1][1],and it not 
 adding array1[2][0]*/
int sum2{0};
for(int i = 0;i< n;i++){

    for(int j= n-1;j >= 0 ; --j){
            sum2=sum2+ array1[i][j];
            // k=k-1;
            cout<<j<<"j"<<endl;
            break;
            }
    n=n-1;
    }
    cout<<sum2;

if(sum1>sum2){
    cout<<sum1-sum2;
}
else{
    cout<<sum2-sum1;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: ***What*** "error"? Do you get build errors? Then copy-paste them in full and complete into the question. Do you get unexpected results? Then for some specific input, what is the expected result and what is the actual result you get? Also please read [ask] as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And please learn how to use a *debugger* to step through your code statement  by statement while monitoring variables and their values. Lastly, please **[edit]** your question to improve it.

Comment: `cin >> n;
int array1[n][n]{};` is not legal C++ (because `n` isn't constexpr).  But `std::cin` shouldn't be needed in a [mcve] anyway - make it _minimal_, with the input array built into the source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don´t see your issue exactly, but your code is kind of weired.

You have a inner loop, that you always break out after first execution. That means you don´t need a loop. I would propose either:

```
int sum2{0};
int tempn = n-1;
for(int i = 0;i< n;i++){

    sum2=sum2+ array1[i][tempn];
    cout<<tempn<<"j"<<endl;

    tempn--;
}
cout<<sum2;
```

or even

```
int sum2{0};
for(int i = 0, int j = n-1;i< n, j!=0;i++,j--){

    sum2=sum2+ array1[i][j];
    cout<<j<<"j"<<endl;
}
cout<<sum2;
```

But the hint to start debugging yourself is anyway a good idea.

Comment: I didn't notice the `break` in inner loop... ;-)